# lldb: how to show source centered at current execution line?

Tags: debugging, lldb

Whenever hitting 'next' command in lldb, the debugger executes the next command, but it also shows source code centered at the next command to be executed.

How can i make the debugger show such source code information w/o executing anything? simply display the source code on current location.

I want to be able to get that information in a very simple/short command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `frame select <IDX>` command will show the frame at IDX, with the same stop display you would get when a `next` command completes.  So

```
(lldb) frame select 0
```

will display the current frame at the point of execution.  Since lldb does shortest match completion, you can actually type this

```
(lldb) fr s 0
```

but even that's too long for so common a command, so `f` was added as an alias for `frame select`.  So you could type:

```
(lldb) f 0
```

Further, the default value for the frame index, if not provided, is 0, so if you want to focus on the currently executing frame:

```
(lldb) f
```

will do.